# Does all asymmetric encryption schemes rely on a third party?

Tags: asymmetric

Im thinking of schemes like onion encryption, IBE, ABE, Blind Signatures.

Comment: This question isn't super clear as it is currently stated, or I'm not reading correctly. A third party is necessary to validate or prove the authenticity of those involved in an asymmetric encryption scheme, but you can use many asymmetric schemes without any third parties.

Comment: thanks. For instance in group based signature scheme is the group manager a third party? Is a third party any entity responsible for verifying the signatures?

Answer (score 3):

No. Asymmetric encryption works between just two people. A *trusted* third party is generally used to validate public keys.

Comment: I think most of the applications nowadays don't use 3rd party for validation at all. Their developers store the self-signed root certificate in the client app and use it for authenticity just like your browser does. Is it correct?

Comment: HTTPS for browsers all rely on 3rd parties so this is definitely common